# SharePoint 2013 Document Library Template

Tags: list-definition, 2013

I'm in the process of migrating code from SP 2010 to SP 2013. I have a document library (both definition and instance) which is defined via XML in a Visual Studio project. I moved the definition into a SharePoint 2013 project (I wish there was a way to migrate the projects automatically...) and it deploys fine, but I notice the document library is still using the old SharePoint 2010 look, not the new SharePoint 2013 document library look.

I assume it's just a case of changing the template number in the Elements.xml "DocumentTemplate" attribute, but I'm unsure what it should be changed to, or if that's the only thing that needs to be changed.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did yu said VS 2013 ? you mean visual studio 2013 :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out a lot more than just the template number changed. You actually are better off just creating a new list through Visual Studio and giving it the same properties and customizations as your old list that you wanted to migrate. There's a whole lot of other files related to the list that have been updated.